# Estimation with iid uniformly RVs

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, estimation, parameter-estimation

**Problem** Let $Y_i, X, V_i$ be scalar random variables $\forall i=1,2,\dots, p$, defined as follow:

- $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{x}, \sigma_x^2)$, i.e. $X$ is a Gaussian variables with expected value $\bar{x}$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$;
- $V_i \sim \mathcal{U}([-\delta, \delta])\quad \forall i=1,2,\dots, p$, i.e. all $V_i$ variables are uniformly distribuited over the interval $[-\delta, \delta]$;
- $V_i,\dots,V_p$ are independent each other;
- $V_i \perp X \quad \forall i=1,2,\dots, p$, i.e. all $V_i$ variables are uncorrelated with $X$;
- $Y_i\triangleq X + V_i \quad \forall i=1,2,\dots, p$.

For the following linear model 
$$Y\triangleq CX+V $$
where

$$Y\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}
    Y_1  \\ 
    \vdots  \\  
    Y_p     
\end{bmatrix} \quad V\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}
    V_1  \\ 
    \vdots  \\  
    V_p     
\end{bmatrix} \qquad
C\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\ 
    \vdots  \\  
    1     
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^p$$

prove, under the hypotesis of $\sigma_x^2\to\infty$ (*no a priori information*), that

1. the MMSE estimation $\hat{x}_\text{MMSE}$ of $X$ based on $Y$ is
   $$\hat{x}_\text{MMSE}=\frac{y_++y_-}{2}$$
   where $y_+\triangleq\max_{1\leq i \leq p}Y_i$ and $y_-\triangleq\min_{1\leq i \leq p}Y_i$;
2. the MSE $\hat{\sigma}_x^2$ of the previous estimation is
   $$\hat{\sigma}_x^2=\frac{6\sigma_V^2}{(p+1)(p+2)}$$
   where $\sigma_V^2\triangleq\delta^2/3$

**Proposed solution of point 2** 
Since equations (1) holds, we can observe that the maximum and the minimum observations in $Y=[Y_1 \dots Y_p]^\text{T}$ are
\begin{equation}Y_+=X+V_+ \qquad Y_-=X+V_-\end{equation}
where the random variables $V_+$ and $V_-$ are respectively the maximum and the minimum components in the noise vector $V$, i.e. $V_+\triangleq\max_{1\leq i \leq p}V_i$, $V_-\triangleq\min_{1\leq i \leq p}V_i$.
It turns out that the MMSE estimator can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}\hat{x}_\text{MMSE}(Y)=X+\mathcal{V}\end{equation}
where we have introduced the random variable
\begin{equation}\mathcal{V}\triangleq \frac{V_++V_-}{2}\end{equation}
the estimation error is $\tilde{X} \triangleq X-\hat{x}_\text{MMSE}(Y)=\mathcal{V}$, thus, since the MSE (Mean Square Error) of an estimator is the expected value of  $\tilde{X}$, follows
\begin{equation}{\hat{\sigma}_X}^2 \triangleq\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[\tilde{X}^2]=\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{V}[\mathcal{V} ^2]\end{equation}
by studing $\mathcal{V}$ we can prove the explicit expression for ${\hat{\sigma}_X}^2$.

**Question** I'm not sure about this last equation because the two expected value are defined over two different PDF, i.e.
$$\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[\tilde{X}^2]\triangleq\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} (x-\hat{x}_\text{MMSE}(y))^2 f_{X,Y} (x,y)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y$$
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{V}[\mathcal{V}^2]\triangleq\int_{\mathbb{R}} \nu^2 f_\mathcal{V} (\nu)\,\text{d}\nu$$
Is it correct my derivation?